# Conditional row formatting jQuery cells in two consecutive row with different values

Tags: jquery

Need to color cells in consecutive row with different formating different from other cells. Conditional raw formating

Pseudopcode would be something like:

```
foreach oddrow in table
    foreach cell in row
        if cellvalue != previosCellvalue(previous even)
              color differently
```

For example:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>2</td>
   </tr>
      <td>1</td><td>3</td>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>4</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td>4<td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

In above table row one cell two and row two cell two will be styled different, all other will retain their style.

Comment: What is the question and what have you tried?

Comment: I have updated. I can do it in Javascript, but as I have come to realize there is always an easy more cleaner jQuery solution from someone out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged it with jQuery, so a solution is:
http://jsfiddle.net/kWeNY/

```
var last, inner;
$('table tr').each(function(i,tr) {
    inner = $.trim($(tr).html());
    if (inner == last) {
        $(tr).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    last = inner;    
});​
```

Well. With your additional pseudo algorithm you can also check only each second row with: http://jsfiddle.net/gbw49/

```
var last, inner;
$('table tr').each(function(i,tr) {
    inner = $.trim($(tr).html());
    if (inner == last && i % 2) {
        $(tr).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
    last = inner;    
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2)')
```

something like this to add css:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('table tr td:nth-child(2)').css("background", "red");
        $('table tr td:nth-child(2)').css("color", "blue");

    });
```

and if you only want to do that for row 1 and row 2, try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
         $('table tr:eq(0) td:nth-child(2)').css("background", "green");
         $('table tr:eq(1) td:nth-child(2)').css("background", "green");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

check this one.i hope i've got the problem right
http://jsfiddle.net/kWeNY/1/

```
    $('table tr:nth-child(even) td:eq(1)').each(function()
        {
            var  firstVal = $(this).text();
            var firstTd = $(this).closest("tr").prev().find("td:eq(1)");
             var secondVal = firstTd.text();
            if(firstVal != secondVal)
            {
                $(this).css({"background-color":"red"});
                firstTd. css({"background-color":"red"}); 
            }
        }
    );
```